# Why does adding a small float to a large float just drop the small one?

Tags: c, floating-point

Say I have:

```
float a = 3            // (gdb) p/f a   = 3
float b = 299792458    // (gdb) p/f b   = 299792448
```

then

```
float sum = a + b      // (gdb) p/f sum = 299792448
```

I think it has something to do with the mantissa shifting around. Can someone explain exactly what's going on? 32bit

Comment: You might want to try changing from float to double, if this is a limits-of-precision problem. Remember, floats round off; if you don't want that behavior, stick with ints or longs or use one of the extended-precision packages.

Comment: So, I'm asking about the mechanics of the rounding off

Comment: Imagine floats were ten-based, and mantissa is just three digits. 99900 is then 999*10^2. Now add 3: 99903. But mantissa is short -> rounding. The same for 2-based, but we now see funky effects on conversions too, because we print in decimal.

Comment: here you have a detailed explanation on what's going on or, in other words, how a float is stored into 32 bits. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: Related: [Why adding big to small in floating point introduce more error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53140098) for a similar case where rounding error is large compared to the smaller operand, but not equal to it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[32-bit floats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) only have 24 bits of precision. Thus, a float cannot hold `b` exactly - it does the best job it can by setting some exponent and mantissa to get as close as possible<sup>1</sup>.  (The nearest representable `float` to the constant in the source; the default FP rounding mode is "nearest".)

When you then consider the floating point representation of `b` and `a`, and try and add them, the addition operation will shift the small number `a`'s mantissa downwards as it tries to match `b`'s exponent, to the point where the value (3) falls off the end and you're left with 0. Hence, the addition operator ends up adding floating point zero to `b`.  (This is an over-simplification; low bits can still affect rounding if there's partial overlap of mantissas.)

In general, the infinite-precision addition result has to get rounded to the nearest `float` with the current FP rounding mode, and that happened to be equal to `b`.

See also [Why adding big to small in floating point introduce more error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53140098) for cases where the number changes some, but with large rounding error, for an example using decimal significant figures as a way to help understand binary float rounding.

---

**Footnote 1:**   For numbers that large, the nearest two floats are 32 apart.  Modern clang even [warns](https://godbolt.org/z/3EGM8x1rs) about rounding of an `int` in the source to a `float` that represents a different value.  Unless you write it as a float or double constant already (like `299792458.0f`), in which case the rounding happens without warning.

That's why the smallest `a` value that will round `sum` up to `299792480.0f` instead of down to `299792448.0f` is about 16.000001 for that `b` value which rounded to `299792448.0f`.  Runnable example [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:24,endLineNumber:3,positionColumn:24,positionLineNumber:3,selectionStartColumn:24,selectionStartLineNumber:3,startColumn:24,startLineNumber:3),source:%27float+foo()%0A%7B%0A++++float+a+%3D+16.000001%3B%0A++++//float+b+%3D+299792458%3B++++++++++//+clang+int-%3Efloat+changes+value%0A++++float+b+%3D+299792458.0f%3B+++++++++//+no+clang+warning%0A%0A++++float+sum+%3D+a%2Bb%3B%0A++++return+sum%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Afloat+bar()%0A%7B%0A++++double+a+%3D+6.0000001%3B%0A++++double+b+%3D+299792458%3B%0A++++float+sum+%3D+a%2Bb%3B%0A++++return+sum%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0Aint+main()%7B%0A++++printf(%22%25f%5Cn%25f%5Cn%22,+foo(),+bar())%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:44.729267853930565,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1300,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O2%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+13.0.0+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:55.270732146069435,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+13.0.0+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:55.270732146069435,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

The default FP rounding mode rounds to nearest with even mantissa as a tie-break.  16.0 goes exactly half-way, and thus round to a bit-pattern of 0x4d8ef3c2, not up to 0x4d8ef3c3.  https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html.  Anything slightly greater than 16 rounds up, because rounding cares about the infinite-precision result.  It doesn't *actually* shift out bits before adding, that was an over-simplification.  The nearest float to 16.000001 has only the low bit set in its mantissa, bit-pattern 0x41800001.  It's actually about 1.0000001192092896 x 2<sup>4</sup>, or 16.0000019...  Much smaller and it would round to exactly 16.0f and would be <= 1 ULP (unit in the last place) of `b`, which wouldn't change `b` because `b`'s mantissa is already even.

---

If you avoid early rounding by using `double a,b`, the smallest value you can add that rounds up `299792480.0f` instead of down to `299792448.0f` when you do `float sum = a+b` is about `a=6.0000001;`, which makes sense because the integer value ...58 stays as `...58.0` instead of rounding down to `...48.0f`, i.e. the rounding error in `float b = ...58` was -10, so `a` can be that much smaller.

There are two rounding steps this time, though, with `a+b` rounding to the nearest `double` if that addition isn't exact, then that `double` rounding to a `float`.  (Or if [`FLT_EVAL_METHOD`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits/FLT_EVAL_METHOD) == 2, like C compiling for 80-bit x87 floating point on 32-bit x86, the `+` result would round to to 80-bit `long double`, then to `float`.)

Comment: are there 23 or 24 precision?

Comment: 23 stored, 1 implicit, total 24.

Comment: Is this behaviour guaranteed by standard to happen in C/C++?

Comment: @TStancek: More or less, depending on [`FLT_EVAL_METHOD`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits/FLT_EVAL_METHOD), for C/C++ implementations that promise IEEE-754 `float`.  Although unlike ISO C specifies, GCC can keep extra precision even across statements, not just within a single expression, when building for targets like 32-bit x86 with x87 FP (instead of SSE/SSE2).

Comment: @Chris: I made a significant edit to this answer, more than I intended to write when I started editing.  I was initially just going to add a short example to show that "shifting the bits out" when aligning the mantissas isn't exactly what happens; low bits still matter for rounding.  But explaining the details of that grew into a big section.  If you want to trim this down, let me know and I can move what I wrote to a new answer.  (If you want to keep it in your answer, that's great.)

Comment: @Chris McGrath What do you mean by "the default FP rounding mode is "nearest""?

Comment: @Chris McGrath "For numbers that large, the nearest two floats are ***32*** apart". Why  it is 32?

Answer (score 3):

Floating-point number have limited precision. If you're using a `float`, you're only using 32 bits. However some of those bits are reserved for defining the exponent, so that you really only have 23 bits to use. The number you give is too large for those 23 bits, so the last few digits are ignored.

To make this a little more intuitive, suppose all of the bits except 2 were reserved for the exponent. Then we can represent 0, 1, 2, and 3 without trouble, but then we have to increment the exponent. Now we need to represent 4 through 16 with only 2 bits. So the numbers that can be represented will be somewhat spread out: 4 and 5 won't both be there. So, 4+1 = 4.

Answer (score 2):

All you really need to know about the mechanics of rounding is that the result you get is the closest float to the correct answer (with some extra rules that decide what to do if the correct answer is *exactly* between two floats). It just so happens that the smaller number you added is less than half the distance between two floats at that scale, so the result is indistinguishable from the larger number you added. This is *correct*, to within the limits of float precision. If you want a better answer, use a better-precision data type, like `double`.

Answer (score 0):

**Another point-of-view: [Pigeon hole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)**

`float` is commonly encoded using 32-bits. Thus only about 2<sup>32</sup> different values can be exactly encoded.
`299792458` is **not** one of them.

Commonly a `float` is encoded as a [dyadic rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational#In_computing) with a 24-bit significand times some power-of-2.

```
float b = 299792458;
// b typically takes on the closest representable float: 299792480.0
printf("%f\n", b); --> "299792448.000000"
```

The next larger representable float is `299792480.0` or 32 away.

---

Adding 299792448.0 + 3.0 is 299792451.0, but that also cannot be exactly encoded as a `float`.  Per the current rounding mode (round to nearest), the `sum` is then again 299792448.0.

```
float a = 3;
float sum = a + b
printf("%f\n", sum); --> "299792448.000000"
```

Had `a = 17;` then the sum 299792448.0 + 17.0 is 299792465.0 would have rounded to `299792480.0`.