# Cuda float precision

Tags: c++, floating-point, cuda, double, precision

Will the float loses its precision when a number is small enough (GPU Kernel, RTX 2060)?

Say,

```
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void calc()
{
    float m1 = 0.1490116119;
    float m2 = -0.000000007450580;
    float res = m1 + m2;

    printf("M1: %.15f  M2: %.15f Res: %.15f\n", m1, m2, res);

}

int main()
{
    calc<<<1,1>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    return 0;
}
```

Results as:

```
M1: 0.149011611938477  M2: -0.000000007450580 Res: 0.149011611938477
```

M2 does not matter in this case, which confuses me.

I know that float number may not be as accurate as expected, but I wonder if there is something wrong that float in the order of 1e-9 is ignored.

Assume that if I want to add a very small number to a given variable (called *M*) gradually, this benchmark would imply that *M* will not change any more finally?

Thank you very much!

Comment: ***Single precision (binary32), usually used to represent the "float" type in the C language family (though this is not guaranteed). This is a binary format that occupies 32 bits (4 bytes) and its significand has a precision of 24 bits (about 7 decimal digits).*** [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic)

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186589/why-does-adding-a-small-float-to-a-large-float-just-drop-the-small-one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186589/why-does-adding-a-small-float-to-a-large-float-just-drop-the-small-one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your observations are correct and they don't have anything to do with CUDA:

```
$ cat t1981.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#ifndef DONT_USE_CUDA
__global__ void calc()
#else
int main()
#endif
{
    float m1 = 0.1490116119;
    float m2 = -0.000000007450580;
    float res = m1 + m2;

    printf("M1: %.15f  M2: %.15f Res: %.15f\n", m1, m2, res);

}
#ifndef DONT_USE_CUDA
int main()
{
    calc<<<1,1>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    return 0;
}
#endif
$ nvcc -o t1981 t1981.cu
$ ./t1981
M1: 0.149011611938477  M2: -0.000000007450580 Res: 0.149011611938477
$ cp t1981.cu t1981.cpp
$ g++ -DDONT_USE_CUDA t1981.cpp -o t1981
$ ./t1981
M1: 0.149011611938477  M2: -0.000000007450580 Res: 0.149011611938477
$
```

> M2 does not matter in this case, which confuses me.

A `float` quantity corresponds to [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) 32-bit floating point.  This number representation has ~23 bits for mantissa representation.  23 bits corresponds to roughly 6 or 7 decimal digits.  The way I like to think about this is that there can be about 6 or 7 decimal digits between the most significant digit you want to represent and the least significant digit you want to represent (inclusive).

> I know that float number may not be as accurate as expected, but I wonder if there is something wrong that float in the order of 1e-9 is ignored.

It's not that categorically, a number of the order of 1e-9 is ignored.  Instead, it's better to conclude that if there are 9 significant digits between the digits in the number(s) that you care about, `float` may be an insufficient representation.  You can easily work with numbers that are in the range of 1e-9, it's just that you may not have good results combining those with numbers in the range of 1e-1, which is what you are trying to do.

> Assume that if I want to add a very small number to a given variable (called M) gradually, this benchmark would imply that M will not change any more finally?

Yes, if you want to handle calculations like this, one possible solution would be to switch from `float` to `double`.  `double` can handle typically 12-15 or more decimal digits of significance.

There are also other alternatives, such as [kahan summations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm), to deal with problems like this.  You could also sort a set of numbers to be added.  In a  serial fashion, or blockwise in CUDA, adding from smallest to largest may give better results than an unsorted or naive summation.

Also note that a typical [parallel reduction](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf) effectively performs the pairwise summation approach discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm#Alternatives) and so may perform better than a naive serial running-sum approach.